# C# LINQ Multiple Line Conditions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, if-statement

```
public List<VehicleOnTaskDetailDto> GetVehicleOnTaskDetailFinished(VotFilterRequest filterRequest)
{
    using VehicleDeliveryContext context = new VehicleDeliveryContext();
    var result = (from v in context.VehiclesOnTask
        join d in context.Departments on v.DepartmentId equals d.Id 
        join dr in context.Drivers on v.DriverId equals dr.Id
        join vehicle in context.Vehicles on v.VehicleId equals vehicle.Id 
        where v.IsDeleted != true
        where v.IsFinished == true
        orderby v.GivenDate descending 
        select new VehicleOnTaskDetailDto{
            VehicleOnTaskId = v.Id,
            VehiclePlate = vehicle.Plate,
            VehicleId = v.VehicleId,
            DriverName = $"{dr.Name} {dr.Surname} - {dr.Mission}",
            DepartmentName = d.Name,
            TaskDefinition = v.TaskDefinition,
            AuthorizedPerson = v.AuthorizedPerson,
            Address = v.Address,
            GivenDate = v.GivenDate,
            ReturnDate = v.ReturnDate
        }).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

I want to add 2 lines of code depends on the DateType filter that comes with VotFilterRequest, similar to shown below:

```
if (filterRequest.DateType == "GivenDate")
{
    where filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.GivenDate
    where filterRequest.LastDate >= v.GivenDate
}
else
{
    where filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.ReturnDate
    where filterRequest.LastDate >= v.ReturnDate
}
```

I know that you can't do this like this but I don't want to repeat my code aswell. Is there any way to do this shortly? Thanks in regards.

Note: Just to be clear, I want to use LINQ Query Syntax, not Method Syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hybrid approach, add filters to recordsets berore using them. For simple `where` it is simplier to use method syntax:

```cs
public List<VehicleOnTaskDetailDto> GetVehicleOnTaskDetailFinished(VotFilterRequest filterRequest)
{
    using var context = new VehicleDeliveryContext();

    var vehiclesOnTask = context.VehiclesOnTask.AsQueryable();

    if (filterRequest.DateType == "GivenDate")
    {
        vehiclesOnTask = vehiclesOnTask.Where(v => filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.GivenDate && filterRequest.LastDate >= v.GivenDate)
    }
    else
    {
        vehiclesOnTask = vehiclesOnTask.Where(v => filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.ReturnDate && filterRequest.LastDate >= v.ReturnDate)
    }   

    var result = (from v in vehiclesOnTask
        join d in context.Departments on v.DepartmentId equals d.Id 
        join dr in context.Drivers on v.DriverId equals dr.Id
        join vehicle in context.Vehicles on v.VehicleId equals vehicle.Id 
        where v.IsDeleted != true
        where v.IsFinished == true
        orderby v.GivenDate descending 
        select new VehicleOnTaskDetailDto{
            VehicleOnTaskId = v.Id,
            VehiclePlate = vehicle.Plate,
            VehicleId = v.VehicleId,
            DriverName = $"{dr.Name} {dr.Surname} - {dr.Mission}",
            DepartmentName = d.Name,
            TaskDefinition = v.TaskDefinition,
            AuthorizedPerson = v.AuthorizedPerson,
            Address = v.Address,
            GivenDate = v.GivenDate,
            ReturnDate = v.ReturnDate
        }).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would it automatically applies first where method (in if-else statement) to the query below?

Comment: Yes, it is how LINQ translator works. Note that i have changed your query to use `vehiclesOnTask` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it easily by using LINQ extensions methods and using `IQueryable` during building the query:

```
var query = context.VehiclesOnTask
    // You'd need to define those navigation properties.
    .Include(x => x.Department)
    .Include(x => x.Driver)
    .Include(x => x.Vehicle)
    .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false)
    .Where(x => x.IsFinished == true);
    
query = filterRequest.DateType == "GivenDate"
    ? query.Where(v => filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.GivenDate && filterRequest.LastDate >= v.GivenDate)
    : query.Where(v => filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.ReturnDate && filterRequest.LastDate >= v.ReturnDate);
    
return query
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.GivenDate)
    .Select(v => new VehicleOnTaskDetailDto
    {
        VehicleOnTaskId = v.Id,
        VehiclePlate = vehicle.Plate,
        VehicleId = v.VehicleId,
        DriverName = $"{dr.Name} {dr.Surname} - {dr.Mission}",
        DepartmentName = d.Name,
        TaskDefinition = v.TaskDefinition,
        AuthorizedPerson = v.AuthorizedPerson,
        Address = v.Address,
        GivenDate = v.GivenDate,
        ReturnDate = v.ReturnDate,
    })
    .ToList();
```

You could also try incorporating the filter in your current query syntax:

```
// for better readability we assign condition value to variable:
var isGivenDate = filterRequest.DateType == "GivenDate";
// and incorporate it in the filter.
where (isGivenDate && filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.GivenDate && filterRequest.LastDate >= v.GivenDate) 
    || (!isGivenDate && filterRequest.FirstDate <= v.ReturnDate && filterRequest.LastDate >= v.ReturnDate)
```

Comment: This would work but if I use this, I would give up using query syntax and turn my function into method syntax. I am trying to use this as query syntax if thats possible

Comment: Why you have added Includes? They are completely ignored after `Select`.

Comment: Wasn't he joins the tables by adding Includes?

Comment: @BatugKocak I think you are one of the five people that actually prefer query syntax. And then you try really hard to write SQL in C#, when you can use good old LINQ method syntax, couple includes and forget about join forever.

Comment: I actually love SQL and new at C# as well as LINQ, so that's why I am prefering query syntax but if everyone uses method syntax, maybe I should too!

Answer (score 1):

**Expression<Func<T, bool>>** can be instantiated and used in the **Where()** method, you have to create this instance before your query:

```
Expression<Func<VehicleOnTaskDetailDto, bool>> filter;
if (filterRequest.DateType == "GivenDate") {
    filter = 
        en =>
         filterRequest.FirstDate <= en.GivenDate
         && filterRequest.LastDate >= en.GivenDate;
}
else
{
    filter = 
        en =>
         filterRequest.FirstDate <= en.ReturnDate
          && filterRequest.LastDate >= en.ReturnDate;

}
```

and use this filter in **where** condition like:

```
...
.Where(filter)
...
```

note:
ternary condition is also a good approach, thanks to Michał Turczyn for his answer.

Comment: If I merge both of your codes, that would work and actually look good but I want to use the Query Syntax. No matter what, thanks for your answer!